# Variable Redirect in SmartCapture form in CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, smart-capture, cloudpagesurl

I have a Smart Capture form with a single yes/no question in a CloudPage that is supposed to have a variable redirect based on what the answer is.

The code for the question in the form is as follows:

```ampscript
<div class="smartcapture-controls" id="likelihood"><div class="sc-formfield-label">Likelihood to recommend</div>
<div class="sc-formfield-input-wrapper">

 <div class="sc-formfield-input"><label><input type="radio" name="Likelihood to recommend" id="Likelihood to recommend" data-field-type="Text" value="yes">yes</label></div>

 <div class="sc-formfield-input"><label><input type="radio" name="Likelihood to recommend" id="Likelihood to recommend" data-field-type="Text" value="no">no</label></div>
```

I added some AMPScript into the greater form to try to make the variable redirect happen:

```ampscript
  %%[
   var @answer, @redirectURL
   set @answer = RequestParameter('Likelihood to recommend')

   if @answer == 'yes' then
  set @redirectURL = CloudPagesURL(1234)
   else
  set @redirectURL = CloudPagesURL(5678)
   endif
   ]%%
```

I added code to the OnSubmit script, as well.

```js
onSubmitGotoUrl":"%%=RedirectTo(@redirectURL)=%%"
```

For the RequestParameter above, I initially used the ID's within the options (id="likelihood to recommend") but, later, I added id="likelihood" to the first div of the question's code and requested that parameter.

When I test the form and click "yes" it redirects to CloudPageURL 5678 instead of 1234. It appears that the "yes" option actually results in a different value that the AMPScript classifies as an "else" value. I have changed just about everything I can and it either continues to do this or results on a loading error.

What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: Where have you placed your AMPscript ... asking as `RequestParameter('Likelihood to recommend')` will have the value after the submission... so you may have to build an intermediate page/code snippet to redirection.... so from SC form page you add `onSubmitGotoUrl":"%%=RedirectTo(@IntermediatePageURL)=%%"... 2. In intermediate Page you can add ur above AMPscript for Redirection using [Redirect()](https://ampscript.guide/redirect/) function